# JqGrid Data from URL

Tags: php, json, jqgrid

I am decoding JSON from an API:

```
$api = "http://xyzdomain.com/api";
$json = file_get_contents($api);
$array = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($array);
```

Here is the sample result of API objects and arrays.

```
Array
(
[status] => ok
[count] => 1
[meta] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
        )

[data] => Array
        (
                [accountid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [all] => Array
                                (
                                    [fans] => 16
                                    [user post] => 333
                                    [user Details] => xyz
                                )
                            [scorelist] => 1
                            [name] => John Doe 1
                            [timespent] => 5887
                            [nation] => usa
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [all] => Array
                                (
                                    [fans] => 123
                                    [user post] => 903
                                    [user Details] => mno
                                )
                            [scorelist] => 6
                            [name] => John Doe 2
                            [timespent] => 1269
                            [nation] => usa
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [all] => Array
                                (
                                    [fans] => 16
                                    [user post] => 303
                                    [user Details] => abc
                                )
                            [scorelist] => 1
                            [name] => John Doe 3
                            [timespent] => 9292
                            [nation] => ussr
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [all] => Array
                                (
                                    [fans] => 16
                                    [user post] => 333
                                    [user Details] => jqr
                                )
                            [scorelist] => 1
                            [name] => John Doe 4
                            [timespent] => 75600
                            [nation] => usa
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I used only three samples above, but it may go up to 500 or more.

I have basically two questions here:

1. I want to make a table using jqgrid or datatables or any other way it looks good.
2. How can I sum timespent where nation is, say, USA in above example?

Comment: I trimmed and tidied your question to get to the heart of the issue faster.

Comment: anyone can i get a direction of code, how can i populate above given example data in JqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timespent_usa = 0;
foreach($array['data']['accountid'] as $account) {

    if ($account['nation'] == 'usa') {
        $timespent_usa += $account['timespent'];
    }
}
echo $timespent_usa;
```

I'm not sure on how you plan on getting the data into datatables, you could just echo the data within each `$account` array within the foreach loop into `<td>` elements.

Comment: Perfect i got this one. it worked like a charm. how can i search in multiple api arrays. like account_id is same in both json decoded arrays. how can i search and merge data from both arrays to maybe a third array.

Comment: That all depends on what you're trying to search and merge based upon. I would not recommend trying to merge the arrays as the API gives it to you, i think it would be best to go over each array and build a custom one depending on what data you want.